# Geometrically decompose this Hadamard matrix

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, symmetry

I'm trying to read [this](https://quantum.country/qcvc) quantum computing explainer. I got to the part where they introduce the Hadamard gate, which is this 2x2 unitary matrix 
$$
H = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$, considered over the *complex* field.

They explain that $HH=I$, and I know from undergrad that $H$ acts as an isometry since its columns are unitary. I know that for any N, all NxN isometries belong to a group whose operation is function composition (or matrix multiplication). But, I want a more thorough understanding of this matrix and similar ones, preferably in terms of symmetry groups.

- What is a conventional name for the group of 2x2 unitary matrices? For now, I'll call it George.
- Can George be generated by a set of rotations and reflections?
- Is George the symmetry group of a set? Maybe the unit circle?
- Can this particular element of George be represented as a series of rotations and reflections? What are they and how did you find them? How many are required?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group of $2 \times 2$ unitary matrices is called $U(2)$.  It is not generated by rotations and reflections, because rotations and reflections 
are real, and not every unitary matrix is real.

$H$ itself is a reflection.

Comment: What axis does it reflect around? And how do you tell by looking at it?

Comment: It reflects across the line generated by an eigenvector for eigenvalue $1$, namely $\pmatrix{1\cr \sqrt{2}-1\cr}$

Comment: I'm looking for explanations rather than just statements of facts. Did you analyze this matrix by doing an eigendecomposition? If so, why?

Comment: It's easy to prove that an eigenvalue of a matrix $M$ that satisfies a polynomial equation $P(M)=0$ must be a root of the polynomial $P$. So here the possible eigenvalues are $-1$ and $1$.  On the other hand, an orthogonal matrix with eigenvalues $-1$ and $1$ is a reflection across the eigenspace for $0$.